# VT-x is enabled, but ubuntu 18.04 doesn't show it

Tags: virtualization, vmware, cpu

I was running VMWare Workstation 14 on Ubuntu 16.04 for months with no problems. After upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 I started getting a VT-x not enabled error message. VT-x is enabled in the BIOS. I contacted VMWare and they tested the hardware and confirmed VT-x support is enabled.

They state there must be an issue in Ubuntu 18.04... I agree.

Has anyone found a solution for this problem?

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              4
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  4
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               158
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7500 CPU @ 3.40GHz
Stepping:            9
CPU MHz:             800.016
CPU max MHz:         3800.0000
CPU min MHz:         800.0000
BogoMIPS:            6816.00
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            6144K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-3
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same exact problem. It happened after upgrading from ubuntu 16.06 to 18.04. Both virtualbox and vmware 15 started having issues where virtualization was not detected. I didn't change the BIOS and virtualization was enabled (I double checked). cpuinfo also showed that virtualization was enabled.

Here is how I fixed it. The idea was to force the bios to wipe its settings and then re-enable virtualization... maybe something got corrupted when ubuntu tried to install its key in the EFI partition.

1. Open the BIOS and restore to defaults. In my case, I had a choice
   between two different defaults one for XP and Win 7 and one for new
   OSes (aka Secure boot settings). I restored to the Win8 and above
   settings
2. Reboot
3. Enter the BIOS again and enable Virtualization and Disable Secure
   boot (vmware modules wont load with it on unless you sign them your
   self).
4. Now vmware worked.

Good luck!

Comment: This fixed my problem!!! Thank you so much for this.

Comment: I got following error and In my case Virtualization type:   full.......
do i need to change it ? 
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "aea2fe3d-dec5-4de7-adb8-8515fbd3118a", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole